# $a^b > b^a$ or $a^b < b^a$ which is true if $a>b$ where $a,b$ are positive real numbers

Tags: inequality

I was trying to find a simple relationship between mutual exponentiation of two positive real values, if one of them is greater/smaller to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive $a,b$, note that 
$$
a^b > b^a \iff a^{1/a} > b^{1/b}
$$
so effectively, you're asking whether the function $x^{1/x}$ is increasing or decreasing.  As differentiation will show, this function is increasing for $0<x<e$.  So your statement will hold for $0<b<a<e$.  Note: you may find it easier to consider $\ln[x^{1/x}] = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$.

The opposite will be true for $e<b<a$.  For the case of $b<e<a$, this analysis is insufficient.

Comment: One example of it being insufficient is the special case $2^4=4^2$.

Comment: Thanks man ! actually it is $1<b<e<a$ where analysis is insufficient , for $0<b<1$ and $e<a$, $a^b > b^a$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a=3,b=2$

$2^3 \lt 3^2 \implies b^a \lt a^b$

Consider $a=4,b=-2$

$(-2)^4 \gt 4^{-2} \implies b^a \gt a^b$

So, it can be $b^a \lt a^b$ or $b^a \gt a^b$